# Can't retrieve entity config: Module Sql Setup Error

Tags: database, module, magento-1

In my custom module, while setting sql_setup i got this error,

Can't retrieve entity config: membership/members"

Error Report:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:163:"Error in file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\ems\app\code\local\Att\Membership\sql\membership_setup\mysql4-install-1.0.0.php" - Can't retrieve entity config: membership/members";i:1;s:908:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ems\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ems\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421):
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.0.0')
2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ems\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327):
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.0.0')
3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ems\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235):
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
4 C:\xampp\htdocs\ems\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
5 C:\xampp\htdocs\ems\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
6 C:\xampp\htdocs\ems\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
7 C:\xampp\htdocs\ems\index.php(93): Mage::run('', 'store')
8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:5:"/ems/";s:11:"script_name";s:14:"/ems/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

config file:

```
 <models>
        <membership>
            <class>Att_Membership_Model</class>
            <resoursemodel>membership_mysql4</resoursemodel>
        </membership>
        <membership_mysql4>
             <class>Att_Membership_Model_Mysql4</class>
             <entities>
                 <members>
                   <table>membership</table>
                 </members>
              </entities>
        </membership_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <membership_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Att_Membership</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </membership_setup>
        <membership_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </membership_write>
        <membership_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </membership_read>
    </resources>
```

controller file:

```
 class Att_Membership_indexController extends
 Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

 public function viewAction(){
 $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
 $prefs = Mage::getModel('membership/members');
 echo ("Loading the blogpost with an Id of " . $params['id']);
 $prefs->load($params['id']);
 $data = $prefs->getData();
 var_dump($data);
 } }
```

mysql setup file : mysql4-install-1.0.0.php

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$installer->getTable('membership/members')};
CREATE TABLE {$installer->getTable('membership/members')} (
memberid int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
name text,
type text,
date datetime default NULL,
timestamp timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (memberid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; ");
$installer->endSetup();
```

models file:

```
class Att_Membership_Model_Members extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{
public function _construct(){
$this->_init('membership/members');
} }

class Att_Membership_Model_Mysql4_Members extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract{
public function _construct(){
$this->_init('membership/members','memberid');
} }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all check if your table name is correct

```
<table>membership</table>
```

Also you have syntax error in resource model definition

```
<resoursemodel>membership_mysql4</resoursemodel>
```

`resourceModel` - word "model" should start with capital letter (i.e. Model).

```
<resourceModel>membership_mysql4</resourceModel>
```

After changes clear cache.

Comment: Thanks a lot oleksii, After changing `<resoursemodel>membership_mysql4</resoursemodel>` to `<resourceModel>membership_mysql4</resourceModel>` its work well

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my class name wasn't the same with the last part of the name from my custom table.

Example:

class name was: `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Resource_Order` and my table was `mynamespace_mymodule_orders`, so I changed my model, my resource model and the collection model into `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Resource_Orders`.

I posted this, maybe will help someone. Thnx